What to do with recovered account from failed deployment / deployment 2nd signer?
After my anchor deploy command failed with intermediate account's ephemeral keypair ...
Then I recovered the seedphrase keypair from given seedphrase:
solana-keygen recover -o recover.json

The recovered pubkey matches the deployment 2nd signer.
Then I resumed the deployment:
solana program deploy --buffer recover.json --upgrade-authority UPGRADE_AUTHORITY_KEYPAIR 
--program-id PROGRAM_KEYPAIR ./target/deploy/xyz.so

Then it seemed to work...
solana program show --programs

shows my deployed program Id, its slot, authority, and balance
solana program show --buffers

shows nothing
Was the resumed deployment successful?
I still can see the 2nd signer listed on the program deployment signature page on SolScan.io... https://solscan.io/tx/5sMHGfi1v4EHmL5o3vrw7p6PBfTU9aHUAjfJjAcJpkr5X33UzejZPmR9K66AmM1yTxQjrd8p4GfVVgBhLJZkNzde
What about that 2nd signer account fp7vqEcJ8ArvKsjwuTMvAmZS9r88PvtSwnaGDABQkFc?
What should I do with that 2nd signer account, which is on curve ?
Reference: https://docs.anza.xyz/cli/examples/deploy-a-program/#resuming-a-failed-deploy

Yep, this means your deployment was successful! During an upgrade, the steps are roughly:

create a buffer account (recovery.json). This step requires a signature from recovery.json.
write the program binary into the buffer account (requires a signature from the buffer authority)
swap the contents of the buffer into the program account
close the buffer account, send its lamports to the deployer

Because of that last step, you shouldn't see that buffer account under your control.
